# Serverless Framework - How to merge module resources into cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I'm having trouble merging my `module/awsm.json` into `resources-cf.json`.  Nothing I'm trying will merge them.  Here are my steps

1. `jaws project create`
2. `cd new-project-name`
3. `jaws module create greetings hello`
4. modify `greetings/awsm.json` adding `LambdaIamPolicyDocumentStatements` and Resources.  Similar to `https://github.com/dekz/awsm-users/blob/master/awsm.json`.

"`jaws deploy resources`" does not update the cloud formation and produces -

```
JAWS: Resources Deployer  "dev": Deploying resources to region "us-west-2"...  
JAWS: Resources Deployer  "dev - us-west-2":  Performing Cloudformation     stack update.  This could take a while depending on how many resources you     are updating...  
JAWS: Resources Deployer  "dev - us-west-2":  Cloud formation stack update failed because of the following error...  
{ [ValidationError: No updates are to be performed.]
  cause: 
   { [ValidationError: No updates are to be performed.]
     message: 'No updates are to be performed.',
     code: 'ValidationError',
     time: Sun Oct 11 2015 00:13:53 GMT-0700 (MST),
     statusCode: 400,
     retryable: false,
     retryDelay: 30 },
  isOperational: true,
  code: 'ValidationError',
  time: Sun Oct 11 2015 00:13:53 GMT-0700 (MST),
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 30 }
```

Redeploying the lambda and endpoint does not update the cloud formation resources either.

What is the proper process to get the changes into the `resources-cf.json` and apply them on AWS?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.The cloudformation/<stage>/<region>/resources-cf.json is never updated even if I update the awsm.json of my custom module. Still no idea on your side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, on 1.3.3, there is no automation for generating `resources-cf.json` from the `awsm.json` as I expected it to be as well.

From their [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/jaws-framework/JAWS):

> resources part of awsm-module can update main resources cf file on the first install (through the post install step), but that is it for now. There is no tooling at the moment to do the same thing when you add changes to your module manually. For now such changes have to be moved by hand to the appropriate resources-cf file. Future versions of JAWS should bring support for commands that allow rebuilding resources-cf file from information stored inside the awsm-modules, as some people requested that feature.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this question when I had a similar problem.  In my case, setting the region and stage specifically deployed successfully.

Are you sure that you haven't deployed the resources to a different stage and/or region, and that's why AWS is giving you the validation error (i.e., in that region/stage, your stack is already up to date)?

Here's what I ran:

`jaws deploy resources staging us-east-1`

After editing my `cloudformation/staging/us-east-1/resources-cf.json` file.

Then I confirmed via the AWS Web Console that the changes were indeed in effect.